# ColumnHideCommand makes the table columns to disappear in NatTable, when all table elements are selected

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I have a NatTable component with the following layers:

- ViewportLayer
- SelectionLayer
- RowHideShowLayer
- ColumnGroupExpandCollapseLayer
- ColumnHideShowLayer
- DataLayer

I need to show/hide a specific column, when a checkbox selection changes. In order to that, I use the #doCommand() method provided by the NatTable component:

```
if(selection) {
   nattable.doCommand(new ColumnShowCommand(nattable, COLUMN_INDEX));
} else {
   nattable.doCommand(new ColumnHideCommand(nattable, COLUMN_INDEX+1));
}
```

Everything works just fine, excepting the case when ALL the items in the table are selected, and the ColumnHideCommand is executed. On this specific scenario, the whole table content disappears ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUGmN.jpg)). If there is no selection in the table, or not all the elements are selected, then everything works just fine.

Please let me know if you have any idea what's going on there or if you experienced this kind of issues before. My experience with NatTables is quite limited, so please let me know if you need any additional information. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the `SelectionLayer` to support multi column hide operations based on the column selection. A `ColumnHideCommand` get consumed and instead a `MultiColumnHideCommand` is created and executed based on the fully selected columns. The code in charge is located in `SelectionLayer#handleColumnHideCommand(ColumnHideCommand)`. The method is protected, so if you don't need that feature because you only support column hide/show programmatically and not via UI performed by a user, you can override the method to simply perform a `super.doCommand(command);` without the check for selections.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply! I will implemented as you suggested. :)

Can you explain again why does it behave like this by default? What was the reason behind this behaviour, in the first place? To be honest, it sounds a bit confusing for me, but this is probably because I do not have the right knowledge about NatTable. When you have some time please reply with some more details on this matter. Thank you!

Comment: Well the design is like it is, because it was designed for handling user interactions and not for programmatically hiding columns. For programmatically hiding columns you could also try to directly operate on the `ColumnHideShowLayer` API, then the command modification is not performed. But then you need to handle the position transformation yourself (e.g. in case of reordered columns). Maybe we can introduce a flag to the command to not take selection into account in the future to separate user interaction and programmatically handling.

Comment: We also considered to use ColumnHideShowLayer, but this one will not resize the table columns. If you try to hide a column, then the table will not use the whole remaining space. Anyway, I'll stick with your initial proposal, but it would be nice to have a flag or something somewhere in the future (as you suggested). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I don't understand that comment. You said initially that you use the ColumnHideShowLayer. Now you say you don't use it. That doesn't make sense. Anyhow even the ResizeColumnHideShowLayer has API to programmatically trigger hide.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry for the confusion. At the moment I've wrote the question here, I was probably trying with ColumnHideShowLayer, but we also tried with ResizeColumnHideShowLayer (because this one is also resizing the table columns, when columns are hidden). In any case, the method you mentioned in the SelectionLayer is triggered for any of the layers used, so I will implement it as you suggested.